# Finding whether logged user is admin even though app is open in admin mode (Run as an administrator) in msdn in mfc in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, msdn

i am using following code  to Finding whether logged user is admin even though app is open in admin mode (Run as an administrator) in msdn in mfc in vc++.

```
bool  CC_AdministratorDlg::IsAdministrator()
{
    bool bIsAdmin = false;


    try
    {
        // Open the access token of the current process.
        ATL::CAccessToken aToken;
        if (!aToken.GetProcessToken(TOKEN_QUERY))
        {
            throw MAKE_SCODE(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_WIN32,
                ::GetLastError());
        }


        // Query for the access token's group information.
        ATL::CTokenGroups groups;
        if (!aToken.GetGroups(&groups))
        {
            throw MAKE_SCODE(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_WIN32,
                ::GetLastError());
        }

        // Iterate through the access token's groups
        // looking for a match against the builtin admins group.
        ATL::CSid::CSidArray groupSids;
        ATL::CAtlArray<DWORD> groupAttribs;
        groups.GetSidsAndAttributes(&groupSids, &groupAttribs);
        for (UINT i = 0; !bIsAdmin && i < groupSids.GetCount(); ++i)
        {
            bIsAdmin = groupSids.GetAt(i) == ATL::Sids::Admins();
        }
        if(bIsAdmin== false)
        {
            MessageBox(_T("Switch to admin mode"),_T("information"),NULL);
        }


    }
    catch (HRESULT hr)
    {

    }

    return bIsAdmin;
}
```

its working fine when it is open in normal mode .but when i am opening run as an administrator, in this case its  always   returning admin even though user is not admin .Is there way to finding whether logged user is admin even though app is open in admin mode (Run as an administrator) in msdn in mfc in vc++.

Comment: What do you expect? That programming actually run with the administration logon, though it was started from a different logon.

Comment: @Blacktempel: [IsUserAdming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463.aspx): *"**IsUserAnAdmin** is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. [...] End of client support: Windows Vista"*.

Comment: [CheckTokenMembership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389.aspx).

Comment: I think the answer depends on what you actually mean by saing that "user is admin". Would it be okay to refine your question like this: you want to know, if the user who is currently logged on locally (different from the user running your application) is member of local aministrators group?

Comment: can you tell us more info about what you want to do with that "real" user and why you need it?